# If $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere and $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)| = 0$, then $f(z)$ is bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is that true? because if it's analytic then there would be no points of discontinuity, hence it would not go to infinity anywhere

Comment: This is true for every continuous function, even not analytic. You know that $f$ will be bounded outside some closed ball $\overline{B}(0,R)$ because of the assumption on the limit, now $\overline{B}(0,R)$ is compact and $f$ is also bounded on this ball.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic, it is bounded by the argument given by @NaNoS, and so it is constant by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @JulioPuerta so if it's constant and goes to $0$ at infinity, $f(z)=0$ right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Liouville,  if $f$ is not constant,  $f(z)$ is dense.
But outside a ball it's bounded.    And also on that ball.   Contradiction.

---

Or,  being entire implies continuity everywhere.

As suggested,  mere continuity implies the image of any compact set is compact,  hence bounded.

But if $\lim_{\mid z\mid\to \infty}\mid f(z)\mid =0,$ we have, given $\epsilon \gt0,$ that there's a radius $r$ such that outside $B(0,r),$ we have $\mid f(z)\mid\lt\epsilon. $

Putting these together,  we have $\mid f(z)\mid \le M,$ for all $z\in\Bbb C,$
where $M:=\rm max(\mid f(\bar B(0,r))\mid,\epsilon).$

Thus $f$ is bounded.

Comment: So it's bounded inside the ball by Weierstrass theorem, and outside because starting from some large $r=|z|$,it's going to $0$ while being continous